# XML Node to String in Java without XML head tag

Tags: java, xml-parsing

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
out.print("<zhape>"+writer.toString()+"</zhape>");
```

when i use the code above the the following line also appear in the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

How can i omit this and get just the XML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [OUTPUTKEYS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html) to set the property in the [TRANSFORMER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html). To do what you want you should use the [OMIT_XML_DECLARATION](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#OMIT_XML_DECLARATION) output key.

Comment: transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");